# How do I get a decent accuracy with stereoCalibrate() function in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration, triangulation

I'm attempting to be able to triangulate a 3D position using the OpenCV python library by calibrating two cameras and using the stereoCalibrate function. I want the cameras to be able to be attached to the ends of a bar and measure positions around 5m away from the cameras. The majority of code is similar to the code used by Temuge Batpurev (Source: https://temugeb.github.io/opencv/python/2021/02/02/stereo-camera-calibration-and-triangulation.html) and when I run his calibration images through my code, the RSME value ("ret" in his code, retStereo in my code) returned is the 2.4 expected as Temuge outlined.

When I use my own images, which are time-synched through GPS on GoPro 10s, I average around 50. Originally, I thought it was because I was calibrating for too large of an area but close up I still get around 50

Current Calibration Method:
Starting close to the cameras, without the chessboard going out of frame for either camera, slowly waving the board around. Ensuring it runs along the edges of the frames for both cameras as well as the center before moving backwards and repeating this at various depths.

Things I have tried:

1. Increasing the size of chessboard squares (48mm, 61mm, 109mm)
2. Increasing the number of rows/columns on the chessboard
3. Changing lighting conditions
4. More calibration images, I use a script to extract frames from a video so I normally use 20+ calibration frames
5. Using a smaller area to triangulate
6. Seeing if there was a change having one camera at an angle as opposed to having the cameras parallel
7. Checking the findChessboardCorner function actually finds the corners of the chessboard
8. Ensuring the chessboard is in many different positions (bottom corner, top corner, center of the frames for each camera)
9. Moving towards and away from the camera in videos.
10. Changed the criteria and criteria_stereo variables to see if that changed anything

Images of my most recent video, 109mm squares: [image: LHSImage] [image: RHSImage]

My code:

```
############### FIND CHESSBOARD CORNERS - OBJECT POINTS AND IMAGE POINTS #############################

chessboardSize = (8,5) # Other chessboard sizes used - (5,3) OR (9,6)

# Paths to the captured frames (should be in synch) (stereoLeft and stereoRight)
CALIBRATION_IMAGES_PATH_LEFT = 'images_vid\\stereoLeft\\*.png'
CALIBRATION_IMAGES_PATH_RIGHT = 'images_vid\\stereoRight\\*.png'

# termination criteria
criteria = (cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

objp = np.zeros((chessboardSize[0] * chessboardSize[1], 3), np.float32) # creates 9*6 list of (0.,0.,0.)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:chessboardSize[0],0:chessboardSize[1]].T.reshape(-1,2) # formats list with (column no., row no., 0.) where max column no. = 8, and max row no. = 5

size_of_chessboard_squares_mm = 109
objp = objp * size_of_chessboard_squares_mm

# Arrays to store object points and image points from all the images.
objpoints = [] # 3d point in real world space
imgpointsL = [] # 2d points in image plane.
imgpointsR = [] # 2d points in image plane.

imagesLeft = sorted(glob.glob(CALIBRATION_IMAGES_PATH_LEFT))
imagesRight = sorted(glob.glob(CALIBRATION_IMAGES_PATH_RIGHT))

for imgLeft, imgRight in zip(imagesLeft, imagesRight):
    
    imgL = cv.imread(imgLeft)
    imgR = cv.imread(imgRight)
    grayL = cv.cvtColor(imgL, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    grayR = cv.cvtColor(imgR, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            
    # Get the corners of the chess board
    retL, cornersL = cv.findChessboardCorners(grayL, chessboardSize, None)
    retR, cornersR = cv.findChessboardCorners(grayR, chessboardSize, None)

    # Add object points and image points if chess board corners are found        
    if retL and retR == True:

        objpoints.append(objp) 

        cornersL = cv.cornerSubPix(grayL, cornersL, (11,11), (-1,-1), criteria)
        imgpointsL.append(cornersL)

        cornersR = cv.cornerSubPix(grayR, cornersR, (11,11), (-1,-1), criteria)
        imgpointsR.append(cornersR)

        #Draw corners for user feedback
        cv.drawChessboardCorners(imgL, chessboardSize, cornersL, retL)
        cv.imshow('img left', imgL)
        cv.drawChessboardCorners(imgR, chessboardSize, cornersR, retR)
        cv.imshow('img right', imgR)
        cv.waitKey()


cv.destroyAllWindows()

############# CALIBRATION #######################################################

retL, cameraMatrixL, distL, rvecsL, tvecsL = cv.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpointsL, frameSize, None, None)
heightL, widthL, channelsL = imgL.shape
newCameraMatrixL, roi_L = cv.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(cameraMatrixL, distL, (widthL, heightL), 1, (widthL, heightL))

retR, cameraMatrixR, distR, rvecsR, tvecsR = cv.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpointsR, frameSize, None, None)
heightR, widthR, channelsR = imgR.shape
newCameraMatrixR, roi_R = cv.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(cameraMatrixR, distR, (widthR, heightR), 1, (widthR, heightR))

######### Stereo Vision Calibration #############################################
## stereoCalibrate Output: retStereo is RSME, newCameraMatrixL and newCameraMatrixR are the intrinsic matrices for both
                ## cameras, distL and distR are the distortion coeffecients for both cameras, rot is the rotation matrix,
                ## trans is the translation matrix, and essentialMatrix and fundamentalMatrix are self descriptive
                
# R and T are taken from stereoCalibrate to use in triangulation
header = ['Rotation','Translation', 'ProjectionLeft', 'ProjectionRight'] # for the csv file

flags = 0
flags = cv.CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC

criteria_stereo= (cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 100, 0.0001)

retStereo, newCameraMatrixL, distL, newCameraMatrixR, distR, rot, trans, essentialMatrix, fundamentalMatrix = cv.stereoCalibrate(objpoints, imgpointsL, imgpointsR, cameraMatrixL, distL, cameraMatrixR, distR, grayL.shape[::-1], criteria_stereo, flags)
print(retStereo)
print('stereo vision done')
```

Are there any immediate flags with my code or my calibration method? Or recommendations for improving the code? Thanks for taking your time to help me :)

Comment: [edit] your post and add the values of `imagesLeft` and `imagesRight`. *show* at least one pair of pictures, ideally all of them. offer something web-viewable rather than something that requires a download and unzipping. -- are your squares *really* 109 mm large? that's about the width of the palm of your hand.

Comment: Hi I've added a pair, unfortunately I don't have github or bitbucket yet but in the process of doing that now. Those squares are 109mm because they're on the screen, the 68mm and 49mm squares are on cardboard though

Comment: ok so the chessboard needs to cover a good portion of the view, or else your distortion coefficients will just be junk. that means, larger, or closer. -- and holding the pattern parallel to the image plane is literally useless. the data from that contains no information. always hold it at an *out-of-plane* angle. "foreshortening" needs to be witnessed to estimate focal length. a parallel pattern doesn't do that.

Comment: since your lenses look good, you could just skip this all entirely. that'll give you better results than a bad calibration. -- assume zero distortion, principal point in the middle of the picture, and focal length calculated from the size of an object (yard stick) at a known distance.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with my images and get an RSME=0.6202543526131407. So you posted code seems to work fine.

First, I notice some reflections from a lamp or whatever visible on the screen which you are using as calibration board. That might confuse the findChessboardCorners function.
I am not a big fan of using screens for rendering the calibration pattern, since screens are shiny and the resolution is restricted to the resolution of the screen. I suggest buying descent calibration boards. Good ones can be found here https://calib.io/.

Second, move closer to the cameras with your calibration board. The closer, the more details are visible and the better the calibration becomes.

Third, undistort an image from the left and right camera and render them to see if the intrinsic parameters are correct.

Comment: I agree with the board quality statement. Moving closer, can help to improve calibration quality. But is generally more beneficial to calibrate the camera from approximate working distance.